# Passing data without using storyboard or identifiers swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have created a textField in my main viewcontroller and want to pass data to another VC. I have created all of my UI programmatically, with out storyboard.

I tried passing data inside of a action I added to a button by doing the following:

```
let destination = InsuranceInformationViewController()
destination.customerNameLabel = customerNameTextField.text
```

But this does not work for me. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

`   //CustomerInformationViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
view.addSubView(customernameTextField)
view.addSubView(continueButton)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}

let customerNameTextField: UITextField = {
let textField = UITextField()
textField.placeHolderText = "First, Last"
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
return textField
}()


let continueButton: UIButton = {
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
button.setTitle("Continue", for: .normal)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(CustomerInformationViewController ().continueOn), for: .touchUpInside)
return button
}()



@objc func continueOn (){
let destination = InsuranceInformationViewController()
destination.customerNameLabel = customerNameTextField.text
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(InsuranceViewController(), animated: true)        
}
```

//InsuranceViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
view.addSubView(customerNameLabel)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}

let customerNameLabel: UILabel = {
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Name"
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
return label
}()
```

`

Comment: Many questions: Is this the only instance of a `InsuranceInformationViewController` that you're creating in your app?  Do you present it after creating it?  What data type is `customerNameLabel` and how is it declared?

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: Are you assigning text to a label property? Override the setter for `customerNameLabel` and debug there.

Comment: @PhillipMills  the action does push to the InsuranceViewController. I do so like: self.navigationController?.pushViewController(InsuranceViewController(), animated: true)

Comment: @rmaddy the text of the label does not change. Sorry for not being very clear.

Comment: This: `pushViewController(InsuranceViewC‌​ontroller(), animated: true)` creates a new copy of the `InsuranceViewC‌​ontroller`; it's not using the one you used when you assigned the label.

Comment: 1. Where do you set a label's text in the code you posted? 2. Where do you show `destination`?

Comment: @PhillipMills how would I go about sending the data correctly?

Comment: You need to make sure that the object you're updating and the object that you're displaying are the same.  It may be as simple as `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)` but I can't be sure from the fragments of code you've posted.

Comment: @PhillipMills I added more code to the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

When you define destination `let destination = InsuranceInformationViewController()`, you are creating a new instance of InsuranceInformationViewController.

However in doing this, when you are referring to that instance, anything you try to change will not appear to work because it is not the already-instantiated view controller that you see in your view.

Instead you should do something like this:

```
let destination = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOUR_STORYBOARD_ID") as! InsuranceInformationViewController
destination.customerNameLabel = customerNameTextField.text
```

Hope this works

Comment: Thank you for the response, but will this work if I am not using storyboard?

Comment: @Dwendel oh I see you’re issue, and you’re sure you’re overriding loadView() and implementing all of the necessary methods on InsuranceInformationViewController?